# Edit blocked when there is a pending edit and I am review banned

Tags: discussion, edits, review-suspension

I'm blocked from reviewing for some time, but I'm not blocked from editing. I would like to edit someone's question, but there is another suggested edit review pending. I can't approve it because of the review ban, but also I can't do any other edit as when I click "edit" it redirects me to approve the edit. Is that expected or this is a bug?

Comment: I'm not sure what the bug is here. You can't edit since there's a pending edit (as expected) and you're banned from reviewing so you can't review the pending edit (as expected)... A minor UI issue at best, but certainly not a bug.

Comment: @Cai Bug is I have rights to edit posts and can't do edit. Situation described by Glorfindel is also bug for me.

Comment: That's not a bug, that's a feature—no one can edit while there is a pending suggestion.

Comment: @Cai Well, not no one; anyone who can review the edit can edit the post.

Comment: @Servy you need to review the edit first though right? (I can't actually remember)

Comment: @Cai Editing it is *how* you can review it.  It is two of the options as to how to complete the review.

Comment: @Servy ok but regardless of how the UI works it is still a review and if you're review banned you can't review; so no bug.

Comment: @Cai But I'm blocked of doing edit. And in situation described in answer it happens also when no review ban. For me it is at least oversight if not a bug.

Comment: @Cai Agreed.  Never said it was a bug.

Comment: @Kacper You think it's a bug that people who aren't allowed to review edits aren't allowed to review an edit?  I would think that any *other* behavior would be the bug.  If you could review this edit, despite being review banned, then that would be an oversight.

Comment: @Servy I'm saying that having a rights to edit and can't edit is a bug. Nothing to do here with review.

Comment: @Servy yeh I see what you were saying now, my original comment should have been "no one can edit while there is a pending suggestion *without reviewing the suggestion*"

Comment: @Kacper There's *everything* to do with a review.  There's a pending edit.  For you to edit the post while there's a pending edit would necessitate you reviewing the edit, which you've demonstrated you're not ready to do at the moment.

Comment: @Servy OK I understand what you mean. I agree. Just one shouldn't spoent all 20 reviews or shouldn't get banned. However it would be nice to have a possibility to edit event for myself only without posting this edit. Just to reformat code when answering.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not disputing ban. This was done by someone else here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338596/review-suspension-contradictory-recommendation I've just asked a question if such behaviour is bug or not. And I'm meeting coments in tone of: You made wrong review so you was baned why are you disputing that. I don't like it. I'm trying to understand what's going on to improve what I'm doing and instead of some explanations I'm meeting  behaviour that discourage me to participate in comunity. Thank you very much for constructive comment.

Comment: @Kacper If it sounds like that, it's likely because what typically happens is, when people are question/answer/review banned the problem is always with the community and they rarely understand the ban is a reaction to what they did.  If telling you that, this isn't a big, and you should be more careful discourages you from participating in the community then I apologize.  I can supply hundreds of questions, where the author indicates it's the community that should chnage, and not then

Comment: @Ramhound Banning review not discourages me when I understand what happend. It was explained to me and I accepted that. In this question there is nothing about complaining on ban.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there is a pending edit suggestion then ***no one*** can submit an edit ***without first reviewing the suggested edit***. And since you're review banned, you can't perform the necessary review to submit an edit of your own; no bug there.

The fact that it redirects you to the suggested edit *could* be seen as a UI oversight (as [Glorfindel points out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/287663/307988) the same happens when you have reached your review limit), but you're only banned from reviewing—not from viewing suggested edits; so that's debatable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand that to overwrite/improve someone's edit one need priv to review and I agree that whole behaviour of UI is rather minor problem with that redirection than bug in privs.

Answer (score 6):

This happens so rarely that - apparently - the system designers didn't take this possibility into account. The same happens if you would have done 20 suggested edit reviews today already.

Comment: I understand it happens rarely but still it means it is kind of bug or oversight. Don't you think?

Comment: @Kacper a requirement to view a pending edit is the ability to approve or deny the edit.  If you can't do that, you don't meet the requirements, to view the pending edit.  The behavior you describe is purposely done